# Firebird update or insert with generated key

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Firebird 2.5 under Delphi 10.2 w/ FireDAC: I have a table that holds definition data for event handler objects, and a TObjectList of those objects that gets loaded and stored from the table - this table never gets very big, maybe a max of 30-40 rows, often only a handful.  Each row of the table has a PK generated by an after-insert trigger.  I need to be able to update the objects back into the matching table rows, and insert any new entries *and* get the generated PK value back after the insert to keep the object's ID matched.

The UPDATE OR INSERT clause Firebird supports doesn't seem to be suited to cases where the PK is generated by an after-insert trigger, but maybe I'm missing something.

So is there a straightforward way of doing this type of construct?  And considering the small size of the table, would it be more efficient (if not exactly kosher) to just zap the table and insert all new records?

Comment: Are you aware of FireDAC [event alerts](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Database_Alerts_(FireDAC))?

Comment: I have the same problem. The only way I was able to solve it was by using a stored procedure that does the insert after generating the key and returns the generated key.

Comment: Martyn - No, I wasn't.  Thanks for the link - I think I see how to take advantage of this.  About to test it out.

Comment: If only your app uses the db, an alternative is to set up a generator (if you don't already have one) to produce your pk and call it yourself in the table's `OnNewRecord` event.

Comment: `PK generated by an after-insert trigger` how do you do it? after-insert trigger cannot change the column NEW-value like `before-insert` trigger can

Answer (score 0):

The [`UPDATE OR INSERT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html) statement supports the `RETURNING` clause which allows you to return the generated id.

However the main problem is that you say *"where the PK is generated by an after-insert trigger"*. That is not possible, or - at least - if that is what you're doing right now, you are not doing it in the correct way and you are likely using a workaround like using an `update` statement on the table.

The correct way to generate an ID would be in a 'before insert' trigger where the value is set on the `NEW` context (eg `NEW.id = <generated value>`). An 'after insert' trigger cannot modify the `NEW` context, and therefor cannot update column values in the correct way. Updating the value on the `NEW` context in a 'before insert' trigger is also what allows it to be returned using the `RETURNING` clause.

See also ["OLD and NEW Context Variables"](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-oldnew) in the Firebird language reference:

> In all `AFTER` trigger code, the `NEW` variables are read-only

You may also want to read the [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-trgr-create) documentation, which also includes examples on how to generate ids. For another example, see [How to create an autoincrement column?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/).

Comment: Duh! Thanks, Mark - Of course the PK is being being generated in a before-insert trigger, not after-insert.  Brain fart on my part.  I was thinking that, because the return value from the UPDATE OR INSERT is pulled before any after-insert trigger is applied, I wouldn't get it, but since it's in the before event it will be there.  This should work.  Thanks again! :)